# Hazelcast equcalent for Coherence local cache

Tags: hazelcast, oracle-coherence

Actualy we are migrating from Coherence to Hazelcast.

In Coherence we use a local cache like this:

```
    <cache-mapping>
        <cache-name>INFOHUB_PROGNOSE_DATENSATZ_LOCAL</cache-name>
        <scheme-name>default-local</scheme-name>
    </cache-mapping>

    <local-scheme>
        <scheme-name>default-local</scheme-name>
    </local-scheme>
```

Because in coherence are local caches perm mutch better than distributed.

Is there an equvalent in Hazelcast?
Something like force Hazelcast to have the cache just in the local JVM.

A plain java map is no alternative, because of all the great features like eviction that an IMap offers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hazelcast's `IMap`'s is intended to be distributed not local. You can use [near-cache](http://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest-development/manual/html/Performance/Near_Cache/index.html) to keep a subset (even 100%) in the current JVM, but that's more like a materialized view.

However, you can have more than one Hazelcast instance in the same JVM. So you could have a Hazelcast server instance in your JVM with networking turned off. This would provide "distributed" `IMap` but only distributed across that one, so effectively local.