# Is there in Hazelcast a configuration equivalent to Coherence tangosol.coherence.distributed.localstorage configuration?

Tags: configuration, hazelcast, oracle-coherence

Currently, my application runs in a cluster using with Coherence as datagrid and it is configured so that only a few nodes have local partition enabled. It is done by setting tangosol.coherence.distributed.localstorage property.

Now I have to migrate to Hazelcast and I would like to replicate to behavior I currently have with Coherence. 
Is there a configuration in Hazelcast that would allow me to that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hazelcast equcalent for Coherence local cache](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50151418/hazelcast-equcalent-for-coherence-local-cache)

Answer (score 0):

No. There is not, in Hazelcast, a configuration equivalent to Coherencetangosol.coherence.distributed.localstorage configuratiation

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to have a cluster member which does not own any partition storage, the Hazelcast equivalent concept is a Lite Member.

https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/#enabling-lite-members

If you're looking to enable/disable storage at the client side, Hazelcast has near cache, similar to near cache in Coherence.

https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html-single/#near-cache

Comment: I am trying to have some nodes that keep datagrid data while others only access them and  temporary store them in a near cache. I looked at near cache configuration on the reference you suggested but I do not understand how you disable storage and if it is possibile to do so only on maps

Comment: The way you disable storage is by designating a member as a lite member.  A lite member doesn't have partition storage, but it can have near cache.   (Generally this is done for compute intensive applications where you don't need more storage, but need more compute capacity.   In cases that are less compute intensive, having all cluster members provide storage will typically scale and perform better -- is there a particular reason you want cluster members without storage?)

Comment: Yes, my application (it is an online multiplayer game) need to execute heavy computations and reply to user in real time; so I kept datagrid storage and its backup on db on some nodes while others execute only the logic.