# Can Hazelcast be used as a cache manager for a local cache (non-distributed)?

Tags: hazelcast

I have Hazelcast 3.12 integrated in my application and using it primarily as a distributed cache among the nodes in my application.  I now have the need for creating a local/non-distributed cache.  Ideally, I would rather not inject another cache manager in the application.

Is there any way I can configure a Hazelcast cache to work in a non-distributed mode?  I cannot seem to find any cache setting that would allow me to create a non-distributed cache.  I am trying to avoid object collisions between the different nodes.  Additionally, I do not want to guarantee that my objects are all serializable.

Am I forced to make any cached object available to all nodes in the cluster?  I realize that I can programatically create unique cache names on each node to ensure that no 2 members use the same cache, but then I have the issue of data being distributed between all the members which is not desired either.

Is there any way to use Hazelcast locally only?

Answer (score 2):

See [this question & answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50151418/hazelcast-equcalent-for-coherence-local-cache), you can have more than one Hazelcast instance in a JVM, and one of them could be isolated so giving you a "*local*" cache -- distributed, but only distributed on the current JVM.

Hazelcast is intended for distributed caches and you want non-distributed. And, it will insist on serializable cache entries for that reason.

Comment: I hadn't thought of running a second instance.  Not a bad idea.  I would just need to make sure that my objects are serializable.  Thanks.

Comment: "Not bad" doesn't mean it's good, there will be a performance penalty running two instances in one JVM. Not sure also how easy it will be two have two cache managers correctly hooked up to the right instances.